# How to tweet on Follower and Following's timeline from android?

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

How to post on follower and following's wall from android.. also how to get list of user's follower's and following list in android...anyone have any idea..please share with me..Thanks...

Comment: do i understand you right? you want to send a tweet to your follower AND to the people you are following?

Comment: i don't think that this is possible or even should be possible. I think that exactly is the point of twitter that you only receive the messages from people you are following. sorry.